# undefined method ‘bytes’ for for String in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, undefined

I am working with `ruby 1.8.6 (2007-03-13 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]` and I get

```
undefined method `bytes' for #<String:0x2a95ec2268> (NoMethodError)
```

even though my code works on ruby 1.8.7. patchlevel 249
I saw somewhere that you need to add `require "jcode"` for a similar method not defined error with `each_byte`. I tried adding that but it still does not work. Any suggestions are very appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby 1.8.6, you can use my [backports](http://github.com/marcandre/backports) gem:

```
require 'backports/1.8.7/string/bytes'
```

Ta-da, you now have access to `String#bytes`.

You also have all the [many other changes](http://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_8_7/NEWS#LC37) introduced in 1.8.7. And most of 1.9.1, and all of the upcoming 1.9.2, etc...

Comment: You'll need to install it, like other gems, with `sudo install backports`

Comment: I see, I might not be able to do this as I am trying to run a cron job  on my paid hosting account

Comment: You should be able to install gems on any hosting account. Gems are fundamental to Ruby; almost all libraries are packaged this way. You might have to do `install backports` (without the sudo) instead though.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby 1.8.6 doesn't have `String#bytes`. That's a 1.9 addition that was backported to 1.8.7.

You can roughly implement it yourself like this:

```
class String
  require 'enumerator'

  def bytes(&block)
    return to_enum(:each_byte) unless block_given?
    each_byte &block
  end
end unless ''.respond_to?(:bytes)
```

[Note: I haven't checked whether this actually fulfills the contract of `String#bytes` 100%, but it is close enough for my use.]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I noticed something interesting though.
When I run `mystr.bytes.inject{|x, y|(x << 8) | y}` I get a fixnum, but when I run with the code your snippet I get a string object.